# Function to calculate angle to a point in unusual 2D space

Tags: c++, 2d, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I'm looking for a robust function to calculate the difference(delta) between an object and a point.

For example, it there was an object at point A with an orientation of 1.2 Rad, what would be the required angle for the object to turn in order to face Point B.

Furthermore, I'm working in a odd coordinate system where north(0 Rad) faces towards +X, the image below shows this.

[image]

I understand the fundamentals, but I'm struggling to produce something robust.

My c++ function template look like this,

```
    float Robot::getDeltaHeading(float _x1, float _y1, float _x2, float _y2, float _currentHeading) {

    //TODO:

    return xxxxxxx;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers in Advance.

Comment: Please share the work you did and ask a question if you are facing any issues.

Comment: How would you calculate it with pen and paper?

Comment: See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61655425/10979304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer.

```
float Robot::getDeltaHeading(float _x1, float _y1, float _x2, float _y2, float _currentHeading) {

    _currentHeading -= 90;

    double Ux = 0.0, Uy = 0.0, Vx = 0.0, Vy = 0.0, d = 0.0;

    d = sqrtf(powf(abs(_x1 - _x2), 2) + powf(abs(_y1 - _x2), 2));

    Ux = (_x2 - _x1) / d;
    Uy = (_y2 - _y1) / d;

    Vx = cos(_currentHeading * (3.14159f / 180.0));
    Vy = sin(_currentHeading * (3.14159f / 180.0));

    auto ans = 90 + (atan2(((Ux * Vy) - (Uy * Vx)), ((Ux * Vx) + (Uy * Vy))) * (180.0 / 3.14159f));

    while (ans > 180) ans -= 360;
    while (ans < -180) ans += 360;

    return ans;
}
```